# What's wrong with the use of arrayfun and bsxfun?

Tags: matlab

I want to integrate function as follows:

In my code, I define an indicator function as follows:

```
PConstFundingRange=[0:0.25:2,Inf];

PConstFunding=[0,TempFundingInitialPara,0]; % Note that TempFundingInitialPara is constant for each interval) 

FundingInitial=@(t)...
    arrayfun(@(s)PConstFunding(find(s<PConstFundingRange,1,'first')),t);
```

With the function defined, I define another function: the integral of `FundingInitial`:

```
FundingInitialTerm=...
    @(T,t)arrayfun(@(s1,s2)integral(FundingInitial,s1,s2),t,T);
```

My goal is to enter two vectors: `vec1=[1,2]'` and `vec2=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]`  and compute the integral of given function `f(s)` as follows:

[image: required]

Hence, I use the following code:

`bsxfun(@(T,t)FundingInitialTerm(T,t),Vec1',Vec2)`

However, it outputs the following error message:

> Error using `arrayfun`
>   
> All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
>   
> Previous inputs had size 1 in dimension 1. Input #3 has size 41

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

this way integrals can be computed:

```
f= @(s) sqrt(s);
vec1=[1,2] ; vec2=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9];
[V2,V1]=meshgrid(vec2,vec1);
arrayfun(@(low,up) integral(f,low,up),V2 ,V1)
```